# R: Correlation matrix between multiple rows (objects) over multiple columns (variables)

Tags: r, correlation

I'm dealing with a dataframe of multiple rows (objects) over multiple columns (variables). I want to see if any rows (objects) are correlated. I've been through reading corr() and it seems for one variable, I can transpose my dataframe and feed it into the corr() function. but how do I deal with multiple variables of each observation/object? The end goal, plot the correlation matrix on a heatmap to eyeball interesting objects.

Examples as below:

```
Treatment <- c('Drug A','Drug B','Drug C','Drug D','Drug E','Drug F')
Measurment_V1 <- runif(6, 0, 3000)
Measurment_V2 <- runif(6, 0, 20)
Measurment_V3 <- runif(6, 0, 1)
Measurment_V4 <- runif(6, 0, 120000)
Measurment_V5 <- runif(6, 0, 100)

df<- as.data.frame(cbind(Treatment,Measurment_V1,Measurment_V2,Measurment_V3,Measurment_V4,Measurment_V5))
```

Each drug is explained by measurments V1-V5 (in realit there are a few hundreds columns)
So how can get a correlation matrix between all the drugs ABCD then plot their correlation on a heatmap like the Hmisc library could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do it:

```
# Redo your data frame
df <- data.frame(Treatment,Measurment_V1,Measurment_V2,Measurment_V3,Measurment_V4,Measurment_V5)

# Transpose numeric columns
dft <- as.data.frame(t(df[,2:6]))

# Rename vars
names(dft) <- c("Drug_A","Drug_B","Drug_C","Drug_D","Drug_E","Drug_F")

# Correlation matrix
cor(dft)


Output:
          Drug_A    Drug_B    Drug_C    Drug_D    Drug_E    Drug_F
Drug_A 1.0000000 0.9995697 0.9999240 0.9999939 0.9998902 0.9999665
Drug_B 0.9995697 1.0000000 0.9998554 0.9994612 0.9998946 0.9997758
Drug_C 0.9999240 0.9998554 1.0000000 0.9998748 0.9999969 0.9999911
Drug_D 0.9999939 0.9994612 0.9998748 1.0000000 0.9998324 0.9999320
Drug_E 0.9998902 0.9998946 0.9999969 0.9998324 1.0000000 0.9999777
Drug_F 0.9999665 0.9997758 0.9999911 0.9999320 0.9999777 1.0000000
```

You can then use the above correlation matrix to plot a heatmap.

Notice that I used `data.frame()` to redo your data frame since it makes numeric columns.

Comment: but this only returns the correlation between all the variables (columns). I want to get out the observations (Row), each observation is explained by multiple columns (variables). so the end goal is I get a correlation matrix of row to row. The to plot it

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I understand you. If you want to get a correlation matrix of row to row, you can transpose your data frame with `t()` as in `cor(t(YourDataFrame[,c("Variable1","Variable2","Variable3")]), use="complete")`. Perhaps you could edit your question and post an example of what your data looks like?

Comment: yes you are correct, I was sloppy on writing the question. Let me take some examples. Apologies

Comment: Hi @Werner, I think it might worked. However now the correlation matrix are showing only rows and columns by numbers instead of their actual names, so I wasn't sure. I have updated my question, I hope this helps with my aim

Comment: Updated. When you transpose a matrix that has factor variables, it establishes all variables as factors. So you have to select only the numeric variables when transposing. After you do that, run `cor()` on the matrix that you just transposed.

Comment: thank you! yes it worked out like I imagined. Looks like I was stuck in the transpose part. Now I just need to pretty up the heat map. There are 190 treatments in this test data and much more to come haha

Comment: Great. Check out this question about package `pheatmap` I answered last night. You might find the code there useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63944085/using-pheatmap-to-sort-data-by-row-annotations/63948943

Comment: Cheers! Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're actually looking at this problem the wrong way around. You should be treating the drugs as the variables and investigating the correlation structure of the measurements.

I.e. the correlation matrix of interest is

```
cor(cbind(Measurment_V1, Measurment_V2, Measurment_V3, Measurment_V4, Measurment_V5))
```

One approach is to do PCA on the measurements so that you can place the drugs in a standardised space.

Then you could look for clustering of the drugs in that space to see which are similar to each other. Note it's much harder to do clustering in the original space of the measurements as they are on very different scales - you have to standardise them somehow, which is what the PCA can do. It also reduces the dimensionality of the measurement space which will help you visualise what is going on.

Comment: good point on PCA, I actually did that, as well as tSNE and UMAP, at single cell level(the much bigger dataset). Here I'm looking at well level effect of the treatment, and the aim is to have an overview if some drugs are similar. I was hoping that correlation can be a quick dirty way to tell. Although it wasn't clear to me what the correlation of the measurement can tell me. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: The measurements you present looks like many different experiments performed on each drug once (rather than an experiment performed repeatedly on the same drug), so the variation is across the drugs. If the first couple of principal components explain a big chunk of the variance you could just plot each drug's location on a 2d scatter chart and see by eye if there are similarities between the effects of the drugs.

Comment: my bad my friend, sorry for the confusion, the data I'm using for this dirty quick look is actually a table of average measurement of 15 experiments, by doing that I have lost the variation. Previously when I random sample individual cells in the well to perform PCA, guess what, the first 12 PCA explained only ~75% the variance. But very good suggestion.